# Finding taking-off Speed? Help

Tags: physics

An athlete jumps a horizontal distance of $7.18$m. He was airborne for $2.29$ seconds. The acceleration due to gravity is taken as $9.81$ms$^{-2}$. Assume that air resistance is negligible. Calculate the take-off speed in ms$^{-1}$

Comment: What have you tried?  How are you attempting to solve the problem? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: What do you know about this kind of problem? What facts and equations have you seen that deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *horizontal* component $v_1$ of the velocity is an unchanging $\dfrac{7.18}{2.29}$ metres per second.

Maximum height is reached after $\dfrac{2.29}{2}$ seconds. If $v_2$ is the initial *vertical* component of the velocity, then the vertical component of the velocity, after $t$ seconds, is $v_2-9.81t$ (for $t\le 2.29$). This vertical component of the velocity reaches $0$ at time $\frac{2.29}{2}$. It follows that
$$v_2-9.81\frac{2.29}{2}=0.$$
Now we know $v_1$ and $v_2$. The initial *speed* is $\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}$.